# Python multithreading with imagehash module not resulting in faster code execution

Tags: python, multithreading, list, for-loop, python-asyncio

I am wanting to compute 320 million-ish image comparisons which, in my findings, results in an expected execution time of 8-ish days, which if possible I would like to reduce.

I have attempted using multithreading, but to no avail. The time quoted by the module 'tqdm' and by my own rudimentary calculations are the exact same as non-multithreaded code completion estimates.

I want to ask if there is another module I am not aware of that will help aid me with the task at hand. I am aware of asyncio but the implementation is daunting and I have already failed many times in the past attempting its installation. Can someone vouch unequivocally for asyncio before I endeavor my time once again?

My code reads images in from 2 dirs and chucks all the filenames into 2 lists, then using a forloop and 1 nested forloop I am checking all the images in one directory (18,037) against all the images in the other (17,731) and saving the results to a text file with args 'ab'.

PS. I have also tried duping the file 4 times and executing it thru 4 consoles to see if more cpu is consumed and, thus a faster execution time. Alas more cpu is consumed but the execution aint any faster.

Comment: please post your code if you would like to get some help ... but just a small piece of advice try it with a smaller subset (maybe 4 images and 8 or something) to where you can reasonably get the right answer quickly ... then you can try and optimize it

Comment: It sounds like you have a CPU-bound task. Take a look at concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: @dirn oddly enough using 

```with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
 executor.submit(a, 0,  4509)
 executor.submit(a, 4509, 9018)
 executor.submit(a, 9018, 13527)
 executor.submit(a, 13527, 18038)```

has bumped the time estimate to 14 days

Comment: Right. Threads are better at I/O-bound tasks. That’s why I said to look at ProcessPoolExecutor.

Comment: ah I missed that you wrote concurrent.futures. **Process** PoolExecutor not thread, my bad

Answer (score 0):

Multiprocessing has achieved the goal, a way faster code execution and 100% cpu utilisation.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/processpoolexecutor-class-in-python/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html

are useful links.